# What is the difference between "Everybody has something to hide" and "Everybody's got something to hide"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "Everybody has something to hide" and "Everybody's got something to hide" if any?

Comment: There is no difference in meaning.

Comment: "Has" is more formal than "has got".